# Is there any way to find out when will network goes to disconnected in Android?

Tags: android

My question is, Is there any way to find out the network disconnected time? when will it goes off or when will goes On mode?

Thanks in advance For any suggestion and help.

Comment: You want to predict events in the future?

Comment: no no I just i want to get the time of network disconnection by which i can perform some task locally then transfer those task on other side after the connection resuming. I have done the work of popping up the  message when network available or when not. But now i want to get the time when network exactly go down.

Comment: like @kknot says, you can listen to those broadcasts and they will tell you that something about connectivity just changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens to `Intent`s with [android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) action.

```
public class ConnectivityListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // There is action occured with network. 
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(
                Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // query connectivity manager for network state.
    }

}
```

Dont forget to declare this receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name=".ConnectionChangeReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: I already did this in my app for getting the network state where it is connected or disconnected. But my question is how to get the time when network is disconnected or when connected.